# Nodejs: selecting only one option from multiple forms

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap

Let's say I have a page with two forms displaying multiple options as below. As it is, `bootstrap` will allow the user to select two options and pass both fields when the form is submitted.

But I want to force the user to select from one form only, which in my case below means the user can only select a fruit or a drink but not both.

So is there a way to highlight/select only the latest option selected by the user?

I'd like to avoid using scripts if possible.

Thank you for the help.

```
<form action="/orderfood" method="post" role="form">
<div>
  <label>Fruit</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="fruit" multiple="multiple">
    {{#each food.fruit}}
         <option  value="{{_id}}">{{food.fruit}}</option>
    {{/each}}  
  </select>
</div>          
<div>
   <label>Drink</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="drink" multiple="multiple">
   {{#each food.drink}}
       <option  value="{{_id}}">{{food.drink}}</option>
   {{/each}}
  </select>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add radio buttons to the form and use an event handler to listen on either their `changed` or their`click` event and show the `<select>` that matches the currently selected radio button.